# Foreach loop, offset or skip first post in the loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to figure this out for hours but I can't. I just want to show the second post and skip the first one, just like the Wordpress offset function. I'm using AW blog extension for Magento and I want to skip the first post in the recent blog posts. Below is my modified code showing one post recent post in a homepage block. I just want to create another block that will show the second recent post. :(

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts(); ?>
<div id="messages_product_view">
    <?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->    setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
    <?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
</div>

<?php 
 foreach ($posts as $post):
 if ($i++ >= 1) break;
?>


    <div class="postWrapper">
        <div class="postTitle">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="postContent"><?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Any error or it simple doesn't work ?

Comment: [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php)?

Comment: It simply doesn't work, but it works now. I just using Dustin Cochran answer below and the other block I created skipped the first post. :D

Comment: Thanks everyone. Now I'm learning. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to check the count and after printing it stop the loop, otherwise it will loop the entire array to the end and print just the second iteration.

```
$i=0;    
foreach ($posts as $post){
    if ($i==1) {
       //print your div here
       $i++; //added here after edit.
       continue;
    }else if ( $i>1 ){
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This way it will only iterate twice.

Comment: Got a syntax error on this, but It's now working using Dustin Cochran's solution. :D

Comment: Dustin Cochran solution skips the second one and prints all from the second to the last. I only want to print the second post, and nothing more. It tried this, but I can't make it work. Maybe I did something wrong. What I did is is added the my div right after if ($i==1) {

Comment: @jehzlau Its odd because arrays in php starts with count 0 so it will pass right trough it. Now that I'm writing this I just catch a little mistake on my code. I will update it.

Comment: Btw, I'm currently using your code, it works without a syntax error after I removed the endforeach in my code. But the problem now is it only shows the first post. If I update and posted a new article, it will still show the first post. O__O

Comment: Hi Jorge. Here's a screenshot of the code you've shared. :D
http://i.imgur.com/xLy6L4d.png

That shows only one post and only the first posted article. O_O

Comment: Hi Jorge. I didn't notice that you already updated the code. :D It works now and it works perfectly!! O__O THANK YOU SOOO MUCH! YOU ARE A GENIUS! All it takes is the additional $i++; before continue; and it solved everything.

THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOUUUU!!! :) I wish I could return the favor someday.

Comment: Thats great! I'm just glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
foreach ($posts as $post):
if ($i++ >= 1) break;
```

to:

```
//set $i outside of loop
$i=0;    
foreach ($posts as $post):
if ($i==0) {
  $i++;
  //skip the first record
  continue;
}
```

Comment: but it prints all from the second post to all the posts. I don't know where to insert the break now. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?php $i=1;
 foreach ($posts as $post):
 if ($i > 1) {
?>
    <div class="postWrapper">
        <div class="postTitle">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="postContent"><?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php }
$i++;
endforeach; ?>
```